# Get, modify and reupload a Windows10CustomConfiguration object using beta MSGraphSDK v5

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-sdks

I try to find a way to extract a profile from MS Intune using MSGraphSDK v5, then attempt to do some modifications specifically for Windows10CustomConfiguration profile type, and reupload it to the same profile.
(warning : junior developer here...).

These [Windows10CustomConfiguration](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-beta-sdk-dotnet/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Graph/Generated/Models/Windows10CustomConfiguration.cs) are special, because they inherit directly from [DeviceConfiguration](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-beta-sdk-dotnet/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Graph/Generated/Models/DeviceConfiguration.cs)  class, and they also have a [SecretReferenceValueId](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-beta-sdk-dotnet/blob/ba74729a42ffe43458817c0675a054b4ab8d429a/src/Microsoft.Graph/Generated/Models/OmaSetting.cs#L84C24-L84C47)  attribute that you can get its value through [GetOmaSettingPlainTextValueWithSecretReferenceValueId(somerandomID)](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-beta-sdk-dotnet/blob/ba74729a42ffe43458817c0675a054b4ab8d429a/src/Microsoft.Graph/Generated/DeviceManagement/DeviceConfigurations/Item/DeviceConfigurationItemRequestBuilder.cs#L124) from the base RequestBuilder class.

Please consider following code for my idea :

```
using Microsoft.Graph.Beta;
using Microsoft.Graph.Beta.Models;


public static async Task<> CopyDeviceConfigurationProfileFromSrcToDest(string idsource, string iddestination, GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient)
{
    var srcProfile = await GetDeviceConfigurationProfileAndApplyOptionalPatching(idsource, graphServiceClient);
    var dstProfile = await PatchDeviceConfigurationProfile(iddestination, srcProfile, graphServiceClient);
}

public static async Task<DeviceConfiguration> GetDeviceConfigurationProfileAndApplyOptionalPatching(string id, GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient)
{
    // Build the batch
    var batchRequestContentCollection = new Microsoft.Graph.BatchRequestContentCollection(graphServiceClient);

    var singleRequest = graphServiceClient.DeviceManagement.DeviceConfigurations[id].ToGetRequestInformation();
    var singleRequestId = await batchRequestContentCollection.AddBatchRequestStepAsync(singleRequest);
    var returnedResponse = await graphServiceClient.Batch.PostAsync(batchRequestContentCollection);

    var deviceConfiguration = new Microsoft.Graph.Beta.Models.DeviceConfiguration();

    // De-serialize response based on known return type
    try
    {
        deviceConfiguration = await returnedResponse.GetResponseByIdAsync<DeviceConfiguration>(singleRequestId);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"GetDeviceConfigurationProfile failed: {ex.Message}");
    }

    if (String.Equals(deviceConfiguration.OdataType, (new Windows10CustomConfiguration()).OdataType)) 
    {
        // It is easier to use this trick to get access to the list of OmaSettings, than digging into "AdditionalData"...
        var windows10CustomConfiguration = await returnedResponse.GetResponseByIdAsync<Windows10CustomConfiguration>(singleRequestId);

        var batchRequestContentCollectionforCustomConfiguration = new Microsoft.Graph.BatchRequestContentCollection(graphServiceClient);
        var listOfsingleRequestIdsforCustomConfiguration = new List<string>();
        foreach (var omaSetting in windows10CustomConfiguration.OmaSettings)
        {
            var singleRequestforCustomConfiguration = graphServiceClient.DeviceManagement.DeviceConfigurations[windows10CustomConfiguration.Id]
                .GetOmaSettingPlainTextValueWithSecretReferenceValueId(omaSetting.SecretReferenceValueId)
                .ToGetRequestInformation();

            var singleRequestIdforCustomConfiguration = await batchRequestContentCollectionforCustomConfiguration.AddBatchRequestStepAsync(singleRequestforCustomConfiguration);
            listOfsingleRequestIdsforCustomConfiguration.Add(singleRequestIdforCustomConfiguration);

            omaSetting.SecretReferenceValueId = null;
            omaSetting.IsEncrypted = false;
        }

        var returnedResponseforCustomConfiguration = await graphServiceClient.Batch.PostAsync(batchRequestContentCollectionforCustomConfiguration);

        var listOfOmaSettingPlainTextValueWithSecretReferenceValueIdResponse = new List<GetOmaSettingPlainTextValueWithSecretReferenceValueIdResponse>();

        // De-serialize response based on known return type
        try
        {
            foreach (var singleRequestIdforCustomConfiguration in listOfsingleRequestIdsforCustomConfiguration)
            {
                var _OmaSettingPlainTextValueWithSecretReferenceValueIdResponse = await returnedResponseforCustomConfiguration.GetResponseByIdAsync<GetOmaSettingPlainTextValueWithSecretReferenceValueIdResponse>(singleRequestIdforCustomConfiguration);
                listOfOmaSettingPlainTextValueWithSecretReferenceValueIdResponse.Add(_OmaSettingPlainTextValueWithSecretReferenceValueIdResponse);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"GetDeviceConfigurationProfile failed: {ex.Message}");
        }
        // Here I am stuck and do not know what to do...
    }
    return deviceConfiguration;
}

public static async Task<DeviceConfiguration> PatchDeviceConfigurationProfile(string id, DeviceConfiguration body, GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient)
{
    return await graphServiceClient.DeviceManagement.DeviceConfigurations[id].PatchAsync(body);
}
```

- What to do with my listOfOmaSettingPlainTextValueWithSecretReferenceValueIdResponse ?
- How to put them back into the deviceConfiguration original object, because this is needed later for my PatchDeviceConfigurationProfile method.
- An "OmaSetting" object does not have any "value" attribute in its class definition (even if I can see it in VisualStudio during debugging), so extracting the values from the OmaSettingPlainTextValueWithSecretReferenceValueIdResponse objects does not help me much, because I cannot reinject them into a list of OmaSetting.
- Does it mean I have to manually build a JsonNode somehow, and convert that to a JsonDocument, to finally apply it to the "omaSettings" key from deviceConfiguration *AdditionalData*??? Sounds like ultra-pain and error-prone approach...